# Read the GALs based on ABP of user

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I can read all the "global access lists" (GALs) with all users contained therein from the AD using [1].

Outlook does not show all the GALs because an "address book policy" (ABP) is in effect.

How can I filter the GALs down to only those that a certain user is allowed by ABP to see?

[1] http://www.infinitec.de/post/2011/10/25/Searching-the-Global-Address-List-C-Edition.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the msExchAddressBookPolicyLink property from the User Object and then get the AddressBooks that are related to that particular reference policy.

Cheers
Glen